# How to call a ADF Pipeline in other resource group from ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have different resource group and each resource group work on their own domain and ADF pipeleine.
We needs to call all those ADF pipeline from a Since Pipeline . As of now I am not finding a option in Pipeline activity to provide the resource group.

I have tried calling the pipeline from API and use web Activity in the pipeline. But few pipelines run for hours. And many times the API connection getting lost and not able to retrieve the status

Please help me so that I am able to call all the pipelines from single ADF with out any issue.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a good practice. Do you want to call a pipeline from another Data Factory instance?

If that's your case, you can create an Azure function that starts the pipeline you want, and call that functions from your Data Factory.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I feel it's not appropriate to say "This doesn't look like a good practice" . If that would have been the case Microsoft should not have added the pipeline activity. And using a azure function I can call the pipeline but I need to make sure to make the calling pipeline failed on the failure of the inner pipeline and next activity should start on the success of the inner pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web activity to call other pipeline using rest api.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun